# Mashiach for real?

Tags: messiah, messianic-redemption

Is there really such a thing as a ‘redeemer’ to come, a messianic figure?

It seems such a thing can be derived from Scripture, but from which verses did such idea derived in the first place and how do we know that these aren’t talking about something else? 
I mean a lot of people these days, mostly Christians who are claiming certain verses are referring to the Messiah, while in Judiasm they aren’t considered as such. But looking at the Jewish verses cited as proof the plain text often isn’t so explicit or clear.

(I’m asking after being confronted by someone telling me that there isn’t a messiah just a messianic age).

Comment: A rational approach to the messiah and messianic age is to understand them as a gradual evolutionary process. When he biblical prophets spoke about the “end of days,” or “the messianic age,” they had this in mind. When Isaiah described lions lying with sheep and beating swords into plowshares, he was speaking figuratively and poetically about all countries working together to improve themselves and society.

Comment: The Bible does not speak about a messiah (mesheach) arriving miraculously to save the world. Instead the Bible says that if you act well, all will be well. People should work to create such an age rather than rely on miracles.